Simple dependent type example in lean4
import Lean1.Basic

structure ArrayN (n : Nat) (α : Type) where
  array : { array : Array α // array.size = n }

class Hash (HashType: Type) where
  hashSize: Nat
  hash: x -> ArrayN (hashSize) UInt8

structure Private (Key: Type) (HashType: Type) [Hash HashType] where
  keys: ArrayN (Hash.hashSize HashType) Key

structure Public (HashType: Type) [Hash HashType] where
  hashes:
    let n := Hash.hashSize HashType
    ArrayN n (ArrayN n UInt8)

def Public.fromPrivate {K: Type} {HashType: Type} [Hash HashType] (priv: Private K HashType): Public HashType := {
  hashes := priv.keys.array.map (λ key => hash key)
}

The code above gives
invalid field 'map', the environment does not contain 'Subtype.map'
  priv.keys.array
has type
  { array // array.size = Hash.hashSize HashType }

I'm having a little problem working with dependent types. How can I proceed? I know I need to access the inner Array from ArrayN so it will have .map but I don't know how.
Also I probably need to prove that the returned result is the Public type, but I also don't know how

{ ... // ... } denotes a Subtype, which consists of val and property.
Hence, you can call map via priv.keys.array.val.map. Still, this gives you an Array and not an ArrayN so there is still work to be done to wrap the Array into the desired structure but maybe this already helps you to get further here :)

Building on my comment above, it is not too tricky to get your Public.fromPrivate method to work:
def Public.fromPrivate {K: Type} {HashType: Type} [Hash HashType] (priv: Private K HashType): Public HashType := {
  hashes := { 
    array := ⟨
      priv.keys.array.val.map (fun key => Hash.hash key),
      by simp; exact priv.keys.array.property
    ⟩
  } 
}

So to get the desired return type, you already made the right call of creating a record containing hashes but then we need to dig deeper.
hashes is an ArrayN, for which we can again create a record { array := ... }. The thing that goes into the ... must of the Subtype { array : Array α // array.size = n }. We can create an object for this using the magic angle brackets (we could also use a record once again). First, we need to provide the value priv.keys.array.val.map (fun key => Hash.hash key), which is just a plain Array. Second, we need to provide a proof that .size of this array is really Hash.hashSize HashType but this is not hard to show and follows directly from the corresponding property of priv.keys.array after a bit of simplification. Actually simp will do nothing more than applying Array.size_map here.
Hope this helps!
You can find the full example here.
